# external IPs maps to router-admin pages is a big threat to security

Tags: security, internet, network-discovery

when we type the external IP address of some networks, Router's admin page gets loaded.If the admin doesn't request to change the external IP of his network, the network is vulnerable to bruteforce.

1. what is the way to avoid showing up admin login prompt when we just type the external ip in browser?
2. Please mention either router settings or other technical details regarding this concept.Because not all networks show admin prompts when we ping their external IPs

Comment: What model of router please?

Comment: I dont know how this post is migrated from networkengineering to superuser.Because I am new to stackexchange.Anyway all I need is an answer.please help me.

Comment: linksys and teracom

Comment: Then tell us what router model you are using. Usually you have a setting where you can disable this function.

Comment: No it was migrated because you're using a linksys... that's *not* on-topic for network engineering.  Super User handles the kind of "routers with admin pages".  Futhermore we need the exact model number for your linksys and teracom.

Comment: ok thanks for explaining Mike Pennington.someone please answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing a router's admin page when you visit the external IP of a network suggests that the router is configured to allow remote connections to it's administration interface.

You can prevent this by changing the router's settings so that it does not allow remote management. With remote management disabled, visiting the external address of a network should produce an error in the browser.

It isn't possible to provide specific instructions about how to disable remote management without knowing the specific model number of the router concerned however the setting is often labelled `Remote Management` or similar.